# Temporary assignment before the command not working?

Tags: bash

I expected `a` to be something after the initial assignment. But I get nothing.

```
tomas@tomas-Latitude-E4200:~$ echo $a

tomas@tomas-Latitude-E4200:~$ a=0 echo $a

tomas@tomas-Latitude-E4200:~$
```

Similar unexpected behaviour when `a` is set before.

```
tomas@tomas-Latitude-E4200:~$ a=0
tomas@tomas-Latitude-E4200:~$ a=1 echo $a
0
```

Well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary environment variable assigments take effect *during* the execution of the command, not before. In particular, they are not yet effective during the parsing of the command line. Consider the following two commands for illustration:

```
$ A=1 sh -c "echo $A"

$ A=1 sh -c 'echo $A'
1
```

The difference between the example commands is that in the first command the variable substitutions happen *before* `sh -c`, and in the second they happen *during* the execution of `sh -c`.

Technically, the shell adds the temporary variable assignments to the environment of the child process; they are not added to the environment of the shell.